# MonoGame forgets to close window on Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, x11, monogame

I'm trying to do some scientific modelling and I'm creating MonoGame in a separate thread:

```
            gameThread = new Thread(() => {
                game = new Game1(simulation);
                game.Run();
            });
            gameThread.Start();
```

And then at some point of time, user wants to close game window because he's no longer interested in this simulation run.
And perhaps would like to start another one in the same process.
But thing is - MonoGame doesn't close the window, it just hangs it!
I do `game.Exit()` all right on `OnExiting()` - shouldn't I?
gameThread ends. But - X11 game window is now a "zombie window" that gets no redraw but just sits there.

Is there a way to kill this window? Maybe it doesn't bother because usually when game exits it will break X11 connection anyway?

Comment: Not an expert, but I suspect that OnExiting is an event called after Exit is called. So, maybe, your code fall into an endeless loop.

Comment: It's unusual to create GUI elements in a separate thread, and it's also unusual to `Exit()` from a GUI system without ending the process.  I suspect MonoGame was not written with this use case in mind.

Comment: @DietrichEpp MonoGame wants a thread only for itself, and I also have a whole System.Windows.Forms application in my main thread so something has to go in separate thread. Any hacks around it?

Comment: My first idea would be to create a completely separate process to run the MonoGame simulation inside, which makes it easy to know that the game exited cleanly.

Comment: @DietrichEpp it's not a bad idea actually, I think I'll do that as last resort, thank you.